# Meteor.loginWithFacebook not working?

Tags: oauth, meteor, facebook-oauth

having added the **accounts-facebook** package. Im trying to login with facebook following the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice

Having this **button click event**:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({ requestPermissions: ['email']},
function (error) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
});
```

And this setup on the **server**:

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: "facebook"
});
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    clientId: "389711236782370",
    secret: "2wwd9c47589e3eb19e7dbgfb235b6a12"
});
```

Im getting a **undefined client_id** in the facebook login pop-up: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=undefined&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close...

Even if I use the {{loginButtons}} generated by Meteor I get the same result. I have also added the google package and its working perfectly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried setting up Facebook login using the configuration popup provided by `{{loginButtons}}`?

Comment: Hi Rahul, im not getting the usuall configuration popup from the button. It shows as if it were configured already with the undefined client_id url. Its strange. A "Meteor reset" also doesn't help.

Answer (score 20):

Changing **clientId** to **appId** works!

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: "facebook"
});
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "facebook",
    appId: ".........",
    secret: "........."
});
```

Thanks to middle8media in comments: http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-customizing-login

Comment: If this is your actual appID/secret I highly suggest obfuscating it.

Comment: Nope its just some random  numbers I entered.

Comment: This worked for me. However, as for Meteor 0.8+ you need to add the `meteor add service-configuration`package and replace `Accounts` with `ServiceConfiguration`